# Subscribe to observable A when someone subscribe to observable B

Tags: rxjs

I have case where I have an API call that is an observable.
I also have an observable B that track the progress of that query :

```
  generateUrl$(uploadConfig: GenerateUploadUrlVariables, file: File) {
    const generation$ = new BehaviorSubject<ActionWithResult<{ url: string }>>({
      state: 'INIT',
      result: null,
    });

    const complete = function (result: ActionWithResult<{ url: string }>) {
      generation$.next(result);
      generation$.complete();
    };

    this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig).pipe(
      switchMap((result) => {
        generation$.next({ state: 'UPLOADING', result: null });
        const url = result.data.generateUploadUrl.url || '';
        return this.httpClient
          .pipe(
            tap(() => {
              complete({ state: 'SUCCEEDED', result: { url } });
            }),
            catchError((e) => {
              complete({ state: 'FAILED', result: null });
              return throwError(() => e);
            })
          );
      }),
      catchError((e) => {
        complete({ state: ActionState.FAILED, result: null });
        return throwError(() => e);
      })
    ).subscribe();

    return generation$
  }
```

now, I can do

`this.generateUrl$(option, file).subscribe(e=> {console.log(e)})`

and I will get the status of the query, and the result once it is succeded.

But the problem is, if someone mistake and simply do :

`this.generateUrl$()` without subscription, no result will be tracked, but the API will still be call.

I would like to bind the api observable `this.generateUploadUrl` with the tracking observable `generation$`

something like

```
return generation$.pipe(
    whenSomeoneSubscribeToIt(() => {
       this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig)
       .pipe(//all the stuff above)
       .subscribe()
    })
)
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The naive solution

I've created a custom operator that can run an effect after a stream is subscribed to but before it's first emission can be received. I've called it `initialize`, but it's pretty much what you describe with `whenSomeoneSubscribeToIt`.

Here it is:

```ts
export function initialize<T>(
  effect: () => void
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {

  return s => new Observable(ob => {
    const sub = s.subscribe(ob);
    effect();
    return sub;
  });

}
```

Now you can make your subscription an effect:

```ts
generateUrl$(
  uploadConfig: GenerateUploadUrlVariables, 
  file: File
) {

  // Some stuff here

  return generation$.pipe(
    initialize(() => {
      this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig).pipe(
        // some more stuff here
      ).subscribe();
    })
  );

}
```

#### Idiomatic RxJS

You don't really need the `BehaviourSubject` above at all. You're basically using it to imperatively generate a stream.

As another answer noted, you can create the same stream directly to an observer. That approach is a bit better, but still suffers many of the issues that using a behavior subject does. For examples, that answer creates an observable that isn't guaranteed to complete and doesn't manage it's inner subscription when you unsubscribe.

I'd say the idiomatic RxJS approach is to declaratively create the stream you're after using *RxJS* operators.

```ts
generateUrl$(
  uploadConfig: GenerateUploadUrlVariables, 
  file: File
): Observable<StateWithResult> {

  return this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig).pipe(
    map(result => result.data.generateUploadUrl.url || ''),
    switchMap(url => this.httpClient.pipe(
      ignoreElements(),
      startWith({ state: 'UPLOADING', result: null }),
      concatWith(of({ state: 'SUCCEEDED', result: { url } }))
    )),
    catchError(_ => of({ state: 'FAILED', result: null })),
    startWith({ state: 'INIT', result: null })
  );

}
```

One change I've made here is that I'm not re-throwing your errors. It looks like you weren't using them downstream anyways, so this is a cleaner way to handle them. You can (of course!) go back to rethrowing them.

Comment: Interesting answer! similar to what I came up with.  I never knew about `ignoreElements`, so that was a good little discovery for me this morning :-)

Comment: @BizzyBob. :) `ignoreElements` is nice because it tells typescript that the resulting observable has no `next` emissions. Otherwise it's the same as `filter(_ => false)`.

Answer (score 1):

That might be one of the reasons not to use a multi-cast like `BehaviorSubject` in such situations. It'd suit you better to create an observable using the `new Observable()` function.

Note that I've also adjusted some other implementation details like using `finalize` and `error` callback of `tap` operator instead of an inner `catchError` operator.

Try the following

```js
import { Observable, Observer, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, finalize, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

generateUrl$(uploadConfig: GenerateUploadUrlVariables, file: File): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((generation$: Observer) => {
    generation$.next({ state: 'INIT', result: null });
    this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig).pipe(
      switchMap((result: any) => {
        generation$.next({ state: 'UPLOADING', result: null });
        const url = result.data.generateUploadUrl.url || '';
        return this.httpClient.get(someUrl).pipe(
          tap({
            next: (res: any) => generation$.next({ state: 'SUCCEEDED', result: { url } }),
            error: (error: any) => generation$.next({ state: 'FAILED', result: null })
          }),
          finalize(() => generation$.complete())
        );
      }),
      catchError((error: any) => {
        generation$.next({ state: ActionState.FAILED, result: null });
        generation$.complete();
        return throwError(() => error);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the http call fires, even when the consumer doesn't call `.subscribe()` is because you are calling `.subscribe()` on `generateUploadUrl` inside the function.

You can get the behavior you desire (*and what I would say is the proper reactive behavior*) by simply returning the observable returned by `generateUploadUrl` and piping it's result to your desired values. We can use [`startWith`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) to emit your initial values:

```js
  generateUrl$(uploadConfig: GenerateUploadUrlVariables, file: File): Observable<ActionWithResult> {

    return this.generateUploadUrl(uploadConfig).pipe(
      map(result => result.data.generateUploadUrl.url || ''),
      switchMap(url => this.httpClient.pipe(
        map(() => ({ state: ActionState.Succeeded, result: { url } })),
        startWith({ state: ActionState.Uploading, result: null })
      )),
      catchError(() => of({ state: ActionState.Failed, result: null })),
      startWith({ state: ActionState.Init, result: null })
    );
  }
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-70121413?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.

Notice you do not subscribe inside your function, which is what caused the undesired behavior for you in the first place.

If you need the multicast behavior (*in the case you have multiple subscribers*), you can simply add on a [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay) at the end of your pipe.